# Excel VBA: Copy rows where column value is same

Tags: excel, vba

*Aim:* I want to insert the the value in [Col2] & [Numeric Column] as a new row into a template for all where value in [Col1] are same. I also want to use the value in [Col1] in one cell.

*Some additional info:* Column 1 is the identifier/counterpart for an invoice. Column 2 is the type of product and Numeric Column is the currency amount.

I have a table:

`Col1   Col2       Col3      Numeric Column
0001    Value B       Ref1              100
0001    Value B       Ref2              101
0001    Value C       Ref3               99
0002    Value C       Ref4              100
0002    Value B       Ref5              101
0003    Value C       Ref6               99
0004    Value B       Ref7              100
0004    Value C       Ref8              101`

What I am trying to achieve is :

```
Sub Example()
Dim n As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("source")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("target")

For each n = 2 in Range([Col1]) 
  //Where the Values in Col1 are the same

  //Copy Value in Col 1 to Target Sheet in cell A1 {used only once}
  //Copy each value in Col1 - Col3 into row 2 and below for each value where Col 1 is same
```

How do I set a variable that will continue to do something until the same values in [Col 1] are exhausted, then change to the next set of values in [col 1] without having to reference the unique values of [col 1] in a separate table/sheet?

Comment: Unless you absolutely bneed VBA, you could [use a VLOOKUP to return multiple results](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I need to copy the values to a template /populate an invoice. The total number of invoices is in the hundreds so I need to use VBA. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/).  You need something like:

```
 Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
 Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
 Dim i As Long
 With dict
     For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         If Not dict.Exists(.Cells(i, 1).Value2) Then dict.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value2, i
     Next
 End With
```